# getting ACF Piotr Dollar in matlab working

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

http://eavise.wikispaces.com/ACF+training+own+detector 
I followed this tutorial to train the detector of Piotr Dollar and I get some errors. There is a file which I should adapt, my images are 640x480 and I have only one in my database. I am completely new in matlab, please help me. The ground truth file 100001.txt looks like this:

```
% bbGT version=3
doll 217 81 376 366 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

This is the error message:

```
Training stage 0
Error using bbGt>bbLoad (line 231)
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in bbGt (line 88)
[varargout{:}] = feval(action,varargin{:});

Error in acfTrain>(parfor body) (line 247)
      gt=[]; if(hasGt), [~,gt]=bbGt('bbLoad',fs{2,ij},opts.pLoad);
      end

Error in acfTrain>sampleWins (line 245)
    parfor j=1:batch, ij=i+j;

Error in acfTrain (line 136)
    [Is1,IsOrig1] = sampleWins( detector, stage, 1 );

Error in acf_INDUCT (line 44)
detector = acfTrain( opts );

Caused by:
    Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

Comment: matlab reads in the hidden file .directory, I must find a way how to forbid that

Comment: Have you successfully trained the model?